# Python - Error when i replace data of an array by 2 values of a second array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays "Elements" and "nodes". My aim is to gather some data of these arrays. I need to remplace "Elements" data of the two last columns by the two coordinates contains in "nodes" array. The two arrays are very huge, i have to automate it.

An example :

```
import numpy as np

Elements = np.array([[1.,11.,14.],[2.,12.,13.]])

nodes = np.array([[11.,0.,0.],[12.,1.,1.],[13.,2.,2.],[14.,3.,3.]])

results = np.array([[1., 0., 0., 3., 3.],
[2., 1., 1., 2., 2.]])
```

On a last post [Stack'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712943/python-replace-data-of-an-array-by-2-values-of-a-second-array), someone helps me to do it :

```
e = Elements[:,1:].ravel().astype(int)
n=nodes[:,0].astype(int)
I, J = np.where(e==n[:,None])
results = np.zeros((e.shape[0],2),nodes.dtype)
results[J] = nodes[I,1:]
np.concatenate((Elements[:,[0]],results.reshape(2,4)),axis=1)
```

It works here, but when i do on a great number of values, i got an error : "**need more than 1 value to unpack**" but i dont understand what is the origin of the problem...

--- EDIT LATER -----

I think it could be due to the importance of my arrays. Perhaps is there an other way to deal with this problem?
(21536, 4) and Nodes_coord.shape : (10926, 3)

Comment: On which line of your code do you get the error?

Comment: On the " I, J = np.where(e==n[:,None])" I dont know if my values present something wrong...

Comment: Shapes of `Elements` and `nodes` for your actual case?

Comment: In the occasion that you get an error, I'm guessing that `e==n[:,None]` is never true, in which case `np.where` returns a tuple with only a single value, which you're trying to unpack into two values (`I` and `J`).

Comment: Table_connect.shape : (21536, 4) and Nodes_coord.shape : (10926, 3) But it is impossible to be never True :/ A strange value could be present in my data which provoks it?

Comment: `where` returns an array for each dimension of the test.  They may be empty arrays, but still arrays.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using at least one element which does not have a corresponding node.
Try this code to check if this is indeed the case:

```
element_ids = Elements[:, 1]
node_ids = nodes[:, 0]
valid = np.all([elem_id in node_ids for elem_id in element_ids ])
```

I'm guessing `valid` will be `False`.

Comment: Thanks for help and I get "True" :/

Comment: In that case, what does `np.where(e==n[:,None])` evaluate to?

Comment: It returns (array([], dtype=int32),) very strange :/

Comment: This implies that elements in `e` are never equal to elements in `n[:, None]`, which implies that your elements do not have matching nodes.

Comment: Yep but it seems to be impossible :/ thanks for your help ;)