# Replace data of an array by two values of a second array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have two numpy arrays "Elements" and "nodes". My aim is to gather some data of these arrays.
I need to replace "Elements" data of the two last columns by the two coordinates contains
in "nodes" array. The two arrays are very huge, I have to automate it.

This posts refers to an old one: [Replace data of an array by 2 values of a second array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712943/replace-data-of-an-array-by-2-values-of-a-second-array)

with a difference that arrays are very huge (Elements: (3342558,5) and nodes: (581589,4)) and the previous way out does not work.

An example :

```py
    import numpy as np
    
    Elements = np.array([[1.,11.,14.],[2.,12.,13.]])
    
    nodes = np.array([[11.,0.,0.],[12.,1.,1.],[13.,2.,2.],[14.,3.,3.]])
    
    results = np.array([[1., 0., 0., 3., 3.],
    [2., 1., 1., 2., 2.]])
```

The previous way out proposed by hpaulj

```py
    e = Elements[:,1:].ravel().astype(int)
    n=nodes[:,0].astype(int)
    
    I, J = np.where(e==n[:,None])
    
    results = np.zeros((e.shape[0],2),nodes.dtype)
    results[J] = nodes[I,:1]
    results = results.reshape(2,4)
```

But with huge arrays, this script does not work:
`DepreciationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future`...

Comment: I don't see why  bigger size should be a problem.  I get your warning with `e==[]`.  There may be other mis matches that trigger the warning.  For start verify the arrays shapes at the problem line.

Comment: e.shape : (13370232,) and n.shape: (581589,) and this error appears for a critical size because I try to increase arrays until the error

Comment: With those numbers I'd expect a memory error, since `e==n[:,None]` would produce a (13370232, 581589) shaped array.  I won't even try to test that.

Comment: Sorry I was busy. I retained your 1st approach Divakar. It s the very efficient, it works well and it last less 5 seconds!!! Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the game would be to figure out the corresponding matching indices from `Elements` in `nodes`.

**Approach #1**

Since it seems you are open to conversion to integer, let's assume we could take them as integers. With that, we could use an `array-assignment` + `mapping` based method, as shown below :

```
ar = Elements.astype(int)
a = ar[:,1:].ravel()
nd = nodes[:,0].astype(int)

n = a.max()+1
# for generalized case of neagtive ints in a or nodes having non-matching values:
# n = max(a.max()-min(0,a.min()), nd.max()-min(0,nd.min()))+1

lookup = np.empty(n, dtype=int)
lookup[nd] = np.arange(len(nd))
indices = lookup[a]

nc = (Elements.shape[1]-1)*(nodes.shape[1]-1) # 4 for given setup
out = np.concatenate((ar[:,0,None], nodes[indices,1:].reshape(-1,nc)),axis=1)
```

---

**Approach #2**

We could also use `np.searchsorted` to get those `indices`.

For nodes having rows sorted based on first col and matching case, we can simply use :

```
indices = np.searchsorted(nd, a)
```

For not-necessarily sorted case and matching case :

```
sidx = nd.argsort()
idx = np.searchsorted(nd, a, sorter=sidx)
indices = sidx[idx]
```

For non-matching case, use an invalid bool array :

```
invalid = idx==len(nd)
idx[invalid] = 0
indices = sidx[idx]
```

---

**Approach #3**

Another with `concatenation` + `sorting` -

```
b = np.concatenate((nd,a))
sidx = b.argsort(kind='stable')

n = len(nd)
v = sidx<n
counts = np.diff(np.flatnonzero(np.r_[v,True]))
r = np.repeat(sidx[v], counts)

indices = np.empty(len(a), dtype=int)
indices[sidx[~v]-n] = r[sidx>=n]
```

To detect non-matching ones, use :

```
nd[indices] != a
```

Port the idea here to `numba` :

```
from numba import njit

def numba1(Elements, nodes):
    a = Elements[:,1:].ravel()
    nd = nodes[:,0]
    b = np.concatenate((nd,a))
    sidx = b.argsort(kind='stable')
    
    n = len(nodes)        
    ncols = Elements.shape[1]-1
    size = nodes.shape[1]-1        
    dt = np.result_type(Elements.dtype, nodes.dtype)
    nc = ncols*size
    
    out = np.empty((len(Elements),1+nc), dtype=dt)
    out[:,0] = Elements[:,0]
    return numba1_func(out, sidx, nodes, n, ncols, size)

@njit
def numba1_func(out, sidx, nodes, n, ncols, size):
    N = len(sidx)    
    for i in range(N):
        if sidx[i]<n:
            cur_id = sidx[i]
            continue
        else:
            idx = sidx[i]-n        
            row = idx//ncols
            col = idx-row*ncols        
            cc = col*size+1
            for ii in range(size):
                out[row, cc+ii] = nodes[cur_id,ii+1]
    return out
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you consider using `pandas`?

```
import pandas as pd
Elements = np.array([[1.,11.,14.],[2.,12.,13.]])
nodes = np.array([[11.,0.,0.],[12.,1.,1.],[13.,2.,2.],[14.,3.,3.]])

df_elements = pd.DataFrame(Elements,columns = ['idx','node1','node2'])
df_nodes = pd.DataFrame(nodes, columns = ['node_id','x','y'])

#Double merge to get the coordinates from df_nodes
results = df_elements.merge(df_nodes, left_on = 'node1', right_on="node_id", how='left').merge(df_nodes, left_on="node2",right_on = "node_id", how='left')[['idx',"x_x",'y_x','x_y','y_y']].values
```

**Output**

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 3., 3.],
       [2., 1., 1., 2., 2.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's estimate the sizes of the arrays to see if we will encounter a memory error

```
from sys import getsizeof

Element_size = getsizeof(np.random.randint(0,100,(3342558,5))) / (1024**3)
nodes_size = getsizeof(np.random.randint(0,100,(581589,4))) / (1024**3)
result_size = getsizeof(np.random.randint(0,100,(3342558,13))) / (1024**3)

total_size = Element_size + nodes_size + result_size
```

Running this script (`13=(5-1)*(4-1)+1`), the `total_size` is about `0.46 GB`, this means we don't need to worry too much about memory error, but we should still do our best to avoid making copies of an array.

We first create arrays to work with

```
elements = np.random.randint(0,100,(100,5))
elements[:,0] = np.arange(100)
nodes = np.random.randint(0,100,(300,4))

# create an empty result array 
results = np.empty((100,13)).astype(elements.dtype)
results[:,:5] = elements
```

**As you can see, we create the array `results` in the first place, there are two benefits to create this array at the beginning**:

1. Most operations can be in-place operations performed on `results`.
2. If the memory space is not sufficient, you will know this when you create `results`.

With these arrays, you can solve your problem with

```
aux_inds = np.arange(4)
def argmax_with_exception(row):
    
    mask = row[1:5][:,None] == nodes[:,0]
    indices = np.argmax(mask,axis=1)
    node_slices = nodes[indices][:,1:]

    # if a node in Element is not found in the array nodes
    not_found = aux_inds[~np.any(mask,axis=1)]
    node_slices[not_found] = np.ones(3) * -999
    row[1:] = node_slices.flatten()
    
np.apply_along_axis(argmax_with_exception,1,results)
```

in which, if a node in `Element` is not found in `nodes`, its value will be assigned to `(-999,-999,-999)`.

In this approach, `np.apply_along_axis(argmax_with_exception,1, results)` will perform an in-place operation on the array `results`, therefore, it is unlikely you will run into memory error as long as the arrays can be created in the first place. If, however, the machine you are working with has a very small RAM, you can save the array `Elements` to disk in the first place, then load it into `results` with `results[:,:5] = np.load('Elements.npy')`

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand the pythonic solution first look at the solution provided by sgnfis on the old post:
**Old solution**

```
import numpy as np
# I used numpy 1.10.1 here

Elements = np.array([[1.,11.,14.],[2.,12.,13.]])
nodes = np.array([[11.,0.,0.],[12.,1.,1.],[13.,2.,2.],[14.,3.,3.]])

# Create an array with enough rows and five columns
res = np.zeros((np.shape(Elements)[0],5))

for i in range(np.shape(Elements)[0]):
    res[i,0] = Elements[i,0] # The first column stays the same

    # Find the Value of the 2nd column of Elements in the first column of nodes.
    nodesindex = np.where(nodes[:,0]==Elements[i,1])
    # Replace second and third row of the results with the ventries from nodes.
    res[i,1:3]=nodes[nodesindex,1:3]

    #Do the same for the 3rd column of Elements
    nodesindex = np.where(nodes[:,0]==Elements[i,2])
    res[i,3:5]=nodes[nodesindex,1:3]

print(res)
```

The above solution is now turned into pythonic solution as given below:
**New Solution:**

```
import numpy as np

Elements = np.array([[1.,11.,14.],[2.,12.,13.]])
nodes = np.array([[11.,0.,0.],[12.,1.,1.],[13.,2.,2.],[14.,3.,3.]])

# Create an array with enough rows and five columns
res = np.zeros((np.shape(Elements)[0],5))
res[:,0] = Elements[:,0]  # The first column stays the same
res[:,1:3]=[nodes[np.where(nodes[:,0]==Elements[i,1]),1:3] for i in range(np.shape(Elements)[0])]
res[:,3:5]=[nodes[np.where(nodes[:,0]==Elements[i,2]),1:3] for i in range(np.shape(Elements)[0])]
print(res)
```